# In a additive group is it hard to calculate $bg$ given $ag, g, abg$

Tags: elliptic-curves, discrete-logarithm, number-theory, group-theory

The ECDH problem defined that given $g,ag,bg$ it is difficult to calculate $abg$. But it is also difficult to calculate $bg$ given $ag,g,abg$. where $g$ is generator and a,b are elements of group.

Comment: Can you explain the specific relationship to cryptography? Otherwise this should be on a different site. Likely Math or Computer Science.

Comment: Note that $a$ and $b$ are normally *not* elements of the group, they are integers (modulo the order of $g$ if one wants to be pedantic).

Comment: @fkraiem: Exactly, this is what I was just observing.

Comment: yes you are correct a,b are integers not element of group.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is equally as difficult; if we assign:

$$g' = ag$$
$$a' = a^{-1}$$
$$b' = b$$

Then the restatement of your problem is: given $g' = ag$, $a'g' = g$ and $b'g' = abg$, compute $a'b'g' = bg$, which is exactly the ECDH problem.

Now, this assumes that $a$ has an inverse; this is not a problem if the curve order is a prime, and is easy to work around if the curve order is a prime times a small cofactor.

Comment: I think that the problem can't be solved in a general way. Assume if we can define on this group a pairing e. then chosing $x_0$ in such a way that $e(g,x_0)=\alpha$ then if the DLP is easy in this group, then we can solve for any integer a (modulo the order) $e(a.g, x_0)=\alpha^a$. 

It depend on the nature of the group.